# Beracha on Intravenous

Tags: halacha, food, blessing, medicine

There Gemara Berachot 35 says "anyone who enjoys from this world without a Beracha is stealing."

Does one make a Beracha on intravenous feeding?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45495

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28675/759

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Tzitz Eliezer [13:35:3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14512&st=&pgnum=95) brings down not to, the reason being that the throat and taste buds don't get pleasure  ([Minchas Yitzchak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1598&pgnum=40) uses the same reasoning.)

Comment: +1 I see quoted from tzitz eliezer in chelek 12 siman 1 saying this as well, but I haven't checked it up.