# May the Sotah take the bitter waters intravenously?

Tags: halacha, eating, water, parshat-nasso, sotah-secluded-woman

In Naso, we read ([Bamidbar 5:32](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0405.htm)) that the kohen blots out the curses (which include Hashem's name) in the bitter waters and then gives for the woman to drink (5:24).

What if the woman is unable to swallow the waters due to their bitterness?Could she instead take it as an intravenous injection? Or do we insist that she swallow it?

Comment: Isn't the water pretty much 100% water? (I know there's earth in it, but presumably that'd sink to the bottom, no?) Is pretty-much-100% water dangerous as an IV injection? (That's my impression, but I'm untrained in medicine.)

Comment: The question would be improved if you added your basis for thinking that, either in general or in this specific case, an IV might be halachically comparable to drinking.

Comment: It seems that intravenous is not called eating or drinking and the Torah says drink. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16145/beracha-on-intravenous

Comment: Also from the passuk its mashma we force her to drink see loshon of the passuk.

Comment: Re: ["Poe's Law"](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2013/05/may-sotah-take-bitter-waters.html) , note that your actual intent is irrelevant. The acceptability of the question is based on whether the *POV evident in the question* looks sincere and on-topic.

Answer (score 10):

The Talmud (Sotah 18a) records the following question:

> בעי רבא: השקה בסיב, מהו? בשפופרת, מהו? דרך שתיה בכך, או אין דרך שתיה בכך? תיקו.‏
>   Rava asked: If they had her drink [the waters] through a tube, what is the ruling? through a reed, what is the ruling? Is that the manner of drinking or it is not the manner of drinking? The matter remained unresolved.

An intravenous drip of Sotah-water is certainly no better than a straw and is much likely worse. So I would propose that is does not work.