# Drinking medicine with a straw on shabbas

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sources-mekorot, health-safety-shmira, shinuy-deviation

I saw on [Revach.net](http://revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Shearim-Metzuyanim-BHalacha-Spilling-Too-Much-Wine-By-Heseiba-How-About-A-Straw/4480) questions about drinking with a straw and it mentioned that the Mahrsham held that drinking medicine from a straw might be considered a shinui and permitted on shabbas. Does anyone know where this Mahrsham is?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28692/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is found in a gloss of the Maharsham on *Orchos Chayim* ([OC 532:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8760&st=&pgnum=195)):

> ולמאי
>    דאיתא בסוטה י״ח ע״א השקה בסיב ובשפופרת מהו דדלמא
>    אין דרך שתייה בכך אם כן היה מקום להתיר לשתות דרך
>    שפופרת גם בשבת במקום צער באופן זה דבדרבנן כל תיקו
>    להקל ועוד די״ל דבעושה על ידי שינוי ל״ש למיגזר כדאיתא
>    כה״ג בביצה י״ח ע״א מתוך שלא הותרה לו אלא על ידי
>    דליו זכור הוא וכו׳ מתוך שלא הותרה לה אלא ע״י מלבוש
>    זכורה היא ואף דבמחה״ש סוס״י ט׳ הביא בשם התו״ש דבאפשר
>    בענין אחר גם בכה״ג אין להקל הרי כאן לצורך רפואה א״א
>    בענין אחר

See also *Tzitz Eliezer* ([8:15:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14507&st=&pgnum=151)), who quotes this and also cites a similar position of the *L'vush* ([OC 328:39](https://books.google.com/books?id=2bJFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA397)).

Comment: excellent,thanks! I read the pg of the Tzitz Eliezer wondering the whole time where is it until I got to the bottom last paragraph,lol