# Biting food without intent to eat

Tags: halacha, blessing, food

If you bite food without intent to chew and eat it, do you need to make a bracha?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and  thanks for this interesting question! I hope you'll look around the site and find other food for thought, perhaps including our 327 other [tag:food] questions. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features, and also [editing your account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/3120/) to give yourself a name.

Comment: What scenario are you talking about here? Are you asking about chewing gum, for example?

Comment: @Daniel he said "without intent to chew".

Comment: @msh210 He said "without intent to chew and eat". Didn't say anything about "intent to chew without eating."

Comment: @Daniel right you are.

Comment: @msh210 Another possible question is whether you should say a bracha if you have some food that you intend to eat without chewing.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16145/beracha-on-intravenous

Comment: @sam - More than related - it's the basis of an answer. No brocho because "the reason being that the throat and taste buds don't get pleasure "

Comment: as an example if i bite open a tough pitted date in order to remove the pit with no intention of eating the fruit just yet should i make a bracha first

Comment: if you dont swallow anything, then why should you make a bracha. dont think benefit of taste alone is enough. but then again there might some residual stuff you wind up swallowing. even so, safek beracha lehakel. sounds like my limited view.

Comment: You only make a Beracha if you can taste the food

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in Berachos 14a says:

> תניא נמי הכי מטעמת אינה טעונה ברכה והשרוי בתענית טועם ואין בכך כלום עד כמה ר' אמי ור' אסי טעמי עד שיעור רביעתא
>
> Thus it was taught: One who tastes does not need a blessing, and someone engaged in a fast may taste without issue.  How much?  R' Ami and R' Assi tasted up to a Revi'is.

There is a dispute among the Rishonim of how to understand this. Tosefos cites Rabbeinu Chananel that this is assuming the person spits it out, in which case the tasting is not considered a pleasure which needs a blessing

> טועם ואין בכך כלום. פירש ר"ח שחוזר ופולט דלא חשיב הנאה מן הטעימה אבל בולע לא אפילו בשאר תעניות ומשום הכי הפולט אינו צריך ברכה שאינו נהנה

The Tur (O.C. 210:2) and Beis Yosef (ibid) understand the Rambam (Hilchos Berachos 1:2) to mean that one could even swallow the food without needing to make a blessing, up to a revi'is-worth.

> ומיהו מטעמת שטועמת התבשיל א"צ לברך עליו עד רביעית לכאורה משמע אפילו אם הוא טועם ובולע וכ"כ הרמב"ם ז"ל

The Shulchan Aruch (ibid) codifies the opinion of the Rambam, and cites the opinion of Rabbeinu Chananel as "some say."

> הטועם את התבשיל אינו צריך לברך עד רביעית ואפילו אם הוא בולעו ויש אומרים שאם הוא בולעו טעון ברכה ולא פטרו את הטועם אלא כשחוזר ופולט ואז אפילו על הרבה אינו צריך ברכה

The Rema (ibid) says that we follow the lenient opinion in blessings, and therefore we should follow the opinion not to make a blessing even when swallowing.

> The Magen Avraham (O.C. 210:10) argues and says one should make a blessing even on swallowing a small amount (he contends that the Rambam never meant to allow swallowing without a blessing, and there is no such opinion).

Within the opinion that the only allowance is in the case of spitting out the food, the Mishna Berura (210:18) applies this to even a case of chewing the food up and then spitting it out.

From all of the above, it should be evident that according to all opinions one would not make a blessing when you do not intend to eat the food that you put in your mouth.  Even if you put a revi'is-worth into your mouth, only the opinion which allows swallowing a small amount holds that there is a cut-off point of revi'is.